# Javascript and Actionscript creating date object with UTC

Tags: javascript, actionscript

This in javascript works:

```
 var d = new Date('2014-02-08 14:37:12 UTC');
```

but I can't make the same in actionscript, what is the alternative in AS3?

Comment: See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#parse() for supported formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var d:Date = Date.UTC(2014, 1, 8, 14, 37, 12);
```